# Unable to send POST request to .NET API using browser but works with Postman: Troubleshooting tips?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, angular

I'm experiencing an issue where they are unable to send a POST request to their .NET API using their browser but it works with Postman.

```
//angular
const url = "http://localhost:5001/ApplicationManager/saveForm";
    const model = {
      firstName: "1234",
    };
    console.log(model);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }); //{ headers: headers }

    this.http.post(url, model, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log("Form data saved successfully.");
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error("Error saving form data:", err);
      }
    );
```

The code is my Angular sending the post request:

```
[HttpPost("saveForm")]
public IActionResult SaveForm([FromBody] DemoModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Form data saved successfully.");
        // TODO: Validate form data and save to file or database
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model));
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to save form data");
        Console.WriteLine("Error:");
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

this is what received it in .net6

The error I received is an HTTP failure response with a status of 0 and a statusText of `Unknown Error` when attempting to save a form to the URL `http://localhost:5001/ApplicationManager/saveForm`.

```
Post http://localhost:5001/ApplicationManager/saveForm net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I can do a successful post request with Postman but not with my browser.

Tried implementing CORS.

Comment: Remove `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, the Angular will post the request with Content-Type: "application/json". Otherwise, you need to apply `[FromForm]` attribute instead of `[FromBody]` in your API.

Comment: I did everything. i keep getting this error ne.js:2680     POST http://localhost:5001/ApplicationManager/saveForm net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 2):

Your API expecting  `application/json` content type, so  you need to stringify your model

```
let model= JSON.stringify( {firstName: "1234" } );
```

And content type

```
 {headers : new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })}
```

Or if you are using one of  the latest versions of angular just remove header from your code, since angular uses `application/json` by default

```
http.post(url, model)
```

and about net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, try to return something

```
return Ok(model);
```

Comment: Angular by defect send JSON object, so it's unnecessary add the header and stringify the model: simple `this.http.post(url, model)`

Comment: @Eliseo it depends on the version

Comment: true, only since Angular 4 works by defect with JSON :)

Comment: it still doesnt work. i keep getting ne.js:2680     POST http://localhost:5001/ApplicationManager/saveForm net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
schedu